# Parse generic foreign key

Tags: parse-platform

I need to store a reference to a parse model in an external service.
In my code I however just have a model instance, not the model class.
How do i get both an identifier for the model type and the model instance's id?

Comment: What SDK are you talking about? I've been using Parse a long time and I have only the vaguest notion what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a composite key based on the class name and object ID. Eg, `User-JFUB234DF`. Just choose a separator that's an invalid character in a classname to avoid conflicts with actual classnames. You'd need to parse the key to run any lookup to split out the class name and object ID.